# Defining variables in for's parentheses

Tags: c++, for-loop, scope, declaration

I don't understand why variable i isn't known in a whole body of first for.
How does defining variables in for's parentheses work ?
(if do it with int i I still get errors)

```
void cardlike(vector<int> &v)
{
        unsigned max_pos = 0;
        int tmp;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++);
        {
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < v.size() - i; j++)
                        if(v[j] > v[max_pos])
                                max_pos = j;

                tmp = v[max_pos];
                v[max_pos] = v[v.size() - i - 1];
                v[v.size() - i - 1] = tmp; 
        }
}
```

This is what i get from g++ when i'm compiling it with -std=c++11:

```
sortvector.cpp:93:38: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope   
   for(unsigned j = 0; j < v.size() - i; j++)
                                      ^
sortvector.cpp:98:29: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope   
   v[max_pos] = v[v.size() - i - 1];
                             ^
```

Answer (score 10):

You have an unnecessary semi colon after your `for` loop

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++);
```

Remove it

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
```

Also, if you have a mulit-line `for` loop, you really should use `{}` braces

```
for (unsigned j = 0; j < v.size() - i; j++)
                        if(v[j] > v[max_pos])
                                max_pos = j;
```

To

```
for (unsigned j = 0; j < v.size() - i; j++)
{
    if(v[j] > v[max_pos])
        max_pos = j;
}
```

Comment: Might it be a good idea to post _why_? i.e. `for(;;);` loops through the empty statement `;` and `for (;;) x(); y();` will only loop through `x();`.  Maybe something like "Though it should be noted that there is only the one statement in the loop (the `if` statement), it's a good habit to get into even for one-line `if`s as it can help prevent future problems when editing your code"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon here :

```
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                                               ^
```